# Stream-Based Processing of Range Chunks in D

Tags: interface, stream, block, d, monads

I'm looking for an elegant way to perform chunk-stream-based 
processing of arrays/ranges. I'm building a file indexing/search 
engine in D that calculates various kinds of statistics on files 
such as histograms and SHA1-digests. I want these calculations to 
be performed in a single pass with regards to data-access 
locality.

Here is an excerpt from the engine

```
/** Process File in Cache Friendly Chunks. */
void calculateCStatInChunks(immutable (ubyte[]) src,
                            size_t chunkSize, bool doSHA1, bool doBHist8) {
    if (!_cstat.contentsDigest[].allZeros) { doSHA1 = false; }
    if (!_cstat.bhist8.allZeros) { doBHist8 = false; }

    import std.digest.sha;
    SHA1 sha1;
    if (doSHA1) { sha1.start(); }

    import std.range: chunks;
    foreach (chunk; src.chunks(chunkSize)) {
        if (doSHA1) { sha1.put(chunk); }
        if (doBHist8) { /*...*/ }
    }

    if (doSHA1) {
        _cstat.contentsDigest = sha1.finish();
    }
}
```

Seemingly this is not a very elegant (functional) approach as I have to spread logic for each statistics (reducer) across three different places in the code, namely `start`, `put` and `finish`.

Does anybody have suggestions/references on Haskell-monad-like stream based APIs that can make this code more D-style component-based?

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with Haskell, but, please, let me share how I would approach this in D. Maybe it will be of some use.

First-off, I find that

```
if (!_cstat.contentsDigest[].allZeros) { doSHA1 = false; }
if (!_cstat.bhist8.allZeros) { doBHist8 = false; }
```

should be put outside of the function. It depends on the functions being evaluated, and if we want a general solution - we can't leave it.

Similar could be said about the

```
_cstat.contentsDigest = sha1.finish();
```

It's kind of a separate matter what we should do with the results.

So, throwing this stuff outside the function and adding some templates gives the following code

```
import std.digest.sha;
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

void copyToMany(R, T...)(R src, T target)
{
    foreach(element; src)
    {
        foreach(s; target)
            s.put(element);
    }
}

void main()
{
    import std.range: chunks;

    auto input = (cast(immutable (ubyte[]))[1, 2, 3]).chunks(2);

    SHA1 sha1 = makeDigest!SHA1();
    auto reducer = new Reducer!(0, (a,b) => a + b);

    input.copyToMany(&sha1, reducer);

    writeln(sha1.finish().toHexString());
    writeln(reducer.result);
}



class Reducer(alias init, alias Func)
{
    typeof(init) result = init;

    void put(R)(R r) {
        foreach (e; r)
        {
            result = Func(result, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in your code. SHA1 is a value type. If you pass it by value to calculateInChunks the value in main is never updated and the hash you're seeing is the same has as if you never added data to it. One solution is to pass a pointer to sha1 in the main function. It should work with "ref" as well, but ref on a tuple doesn't seem to work? Anyway I'll probably disable implicit copying for Digest structs so these issues will be caught at compile time. (I actually wanted to do this some time ago - and then forgot about it). BTW: with makeDigest: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/4e6fb442

Comment: With some refactoring we get this: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/9a1b9045 Something like copyToMany should be part of phobos, but it's also easy to write it yourself.